# MapReduce using SQL Server as data source

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, couchdb, mapreduce

I'm currently investigating the possibility of using MapReduce to maintain incremental view builds in SQL Server.

Basically, use MapReduce to create materialized views.

I'm a bit stuck atm. thinking about how to partition my `map` outputs. Now, I don't really have a BigData situation, with roughly 50 GB being the max but I have a lot complexity and sort-of implied performance problems. I want to see if this MapReduce/NoSQL approach of mine might pan out.

The thing about MapReduce I'm currently having my issues with is the partitioning. Since I'm using SQL Server as data source, data locality isn't really a problem of mine and thus I don't need to send data all over the place, rather, each worker should be able to retrieve a partition of the data base on the `map` definition.

I intend to fully map the data through the use of LINQ and maybe something like Entity Framework, just to provide a familiar interface, this is somewhat besides the point, but it's the current route I'm exploring.

Now, how do I split my data? I have a primary key, I have `map` and `reduce` definitions in terms of expression trees (ASTs, if you unfamiliar with LINQ).

- Firstly, how do I devise a way for me to split the entire input and partitioning the initial problem (I'm thinking I should be able to leverage window aggregates in SQL Server such as `ROW_NUMBER` and `TILE`).
- Secondly, and more importantly, how do I make sure that I do this incrementally? That is, if I add, or make a change to the original problem, how do I effectively ensure that I minimize the amount of re-computations that need to take place?

I've been looking at CouchDB for inspiration and they seem to have a way to do this, but how do I leverage some of that goodness using SQL Server?

Comment: How is this CouchDB related? Because of Map-Reduce?

Comment: Yes, you can read about that here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Basics

Answer (score 1):

I am facing something similar. I think you should forget windowing functions as it makes your process serialized. In other words all workers will be waiting for the query.

What we have tested and it's 'working' is to partition data into more tables (every month has its x tables) and run separate analytical threads on such partitions. Marking processed/unprocessed/possibly bad/etc data after Reduce.

Tests with one partitioned table brought as a locking escalation issues..

You'll definitely add a little bit more complexity to your current solution.

Comment: As long as complexity is managed at some level, I'm not against it, sounds like a reasonable idea. I'm currently investigating SQL notifications as means to define queues that you can process asynchronously.

Comment: We are managing asynchronous queing in our own app(s), but queuing in db sounds ok.